# Create text on the side of a book

Tags: xetex, thumb-index

Is it possible to put some text on the side of a book (see the figure) in xelatex.

[image: Side]

Comment: I did this for some book and the result is not that impressive and completely relies on the publishers bleed handling and how much you are willing to pay for the paper quality. Also there must be a duplicate here somewhere. The buzz word is thumb index

Comment: @percusse Thanks for the reply. When I search for the thumb index, I am getting something different. http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/thumbs/thumbs-example.pdf or http://blog.maiermarco.com/2009/06/11/poor-mans-thumb-indices-in-latex/178. Just to clarify, I am looking for text on the sides, not markers

Comment: You render the text with bold thumb indices so that when cut by the printer you see the text but on the page they are very thin.

Comment: @percusse thanks. This methods is tricky. If I dont get other solutions I will use it :)

Comment: This is just brainstorming, but perhaps PGF's 3d engine could be of use here.

Comment: @cfr No, that's not my idea :) Use PGF to rotate the box (actually not necessary now that I think about it; I woke up a little earlier than normal) and then use it to take a number of slices squared up against the number of pages or some paper-thickness factor.

Comment: @SeanAllred There is a question here somewhere that does exactly that. You basically clip the same image with sufficienly short but wide rectangle in the bounding box depending on the page number and make it the thumb index. The ink shows it at the edge of the book just like those color codes on the catalogues. It is not that complicated but the printing office needs to be quite precise. .

Comment: @SeanAllred Thanks.  That does indeed sound good. I've deleted my earlier comment to avoid confusion.